# i got hacked and can't type the 'i' key on my keyboard - how do i fix it?

Tags: windows, drivers, security

Some government jobs people are messing with my computer and now i cannot type the 'i' key on the keyboard(i have to 'ctrl-v' the letter). How do i go about fixing this without reformatting the drive? is there a registry key that was deleted?

Comment: How do you know you got hacked?

Comment: ..because there's no 'i' in 'government hacker team' ?  ;)

Comment: More likely that your keyboard is broken than a government type person disabled your i key

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold down Alt, and press 105 on the numpad.  Then release the Alt key.  Or, for a capital i, type 74 on the numpad.
2. Try a different physical keyboard.

Comment: i shit you not that's it's a fbi/fusion center deucebag in the basement of the government building do this - it's not the keyboard.

Comment: Such foul language is not appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Also, try using the On-screen Keyboard. If the 'I' does work there, it's most likely a driver or a hardware issue with your keyboard.